# Is it good if I split my CSS file into multiple files for each page?

Tags: css

I'm Building a website, and It has a lot of pages approximately like 30 pages, and I linked these pages with one CSS file (the main css files) not to mention the other files such as bootstrap.min.css and other plugins that requires their own css files.

My point is that in all of these I'm using like the same css files, but in some pages I don't need all of the properties and styles in main.css file, so I'm thinking that I split that css file into multiple files, and create file called (global.css) and type in the properties that I'll need in all pages, and make another css file for each individual page.

My question is:-

**Is it going to be helpful for the website speed if I split that main css into multiple css files and include only the necessary things for each page?**

Comment: it can improve the loading speed yes. but slightly. you see when your page is loading if a CSS file is too big it takes more time to load the file(download).

Comment: The more files there are, the slower the page load. The smaller those files are, the faster the page load. Results will vary.

Comment: The initial load may be greater for large files but most browsers will cache it for use when navigating through the site.  Loading a new sheet every time will not have this advantage.  Although, smaller separated files may make maintenance easier as you'll know specifically what css applies where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you want to abstracts your CSS files into many different SCSS files and then compiles them into one minified master file. One file for the header styling, one for links, one for typography. I was afraid of SCSS but now love it... Nothing changes in production, you are still running off CSS bit in development you are just making your life that little bit more organised.

Comment: I use this free tool to compile my SCSS... http://koala-app.com/ works great... it finds where all my SCSS files are and then I can point where I want the final master.css file to go.

Comment: I'm already using sass and command line to compile my sass into one main css file (its now 40 kb), I believe it will get more than 100 kb when I finish this project, that's why I asked about this issue.

Comment: What I have done is split up my site into different templates - admin, teach, account, frontend and then split up my SCSS into different categories... typography, buttons etc... then I compile only the categories I need into each of my templates using for example admin.scss and then in that file I only have imports taking what I need for the template.

Answer (score 1):

NO,

you better dont want to do that if your code is small like less that 50kb or even 100kb

also if you provide seperate css for each page browser has to download each css file when user visit that page that will cost you one additional request for every single page this will slow down your page and affect your performace

instead I would suggest when your code goes live compress your code or minified it so youll get the more smaller version of your code

I also suggest to leverage browser caching (using .htaccess if you are using linux server)

above are the things which comes under front end performance improvement